# Make checkbox value append to textbox, separated by semicolon (copy e-mail addresses)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to have a list of checkboxes (e-mail addresses). When boxes are clicked, a textfield blanks and is replaced with values of all checked checkboxes, only separated by "; ".

http://jsfiddle.net/7b5fk/1/ is -almost- what I want, except I don't want the comma spacing. I've tried multiple approaches but still can't get rid of the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `.join(';')` to this line:

```
('#video0_tags').val(allVals.join(';')).attr('rows',allVals.length);
```